# How to dynamically compile code with resources references using properties?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dynamic

I have a problem with compiling code dynamically using below code:

```
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        // Build the parameters for source compilation.
        CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();

        // Add an assembly reference.
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Management.dll");
        // Generate an executable instead of
        // a class library.
        cp.GenerateExecutable = true;

        // Set the assembly file name to generate.
        cp.OutputAssembly = "test.exe";

        // Save the assembly as a physical file.
        cp.GenerateInMemory = false;

        // Invoke compilation.
        CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, "data.txt");
        if (cr.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            // Display compilation errors.
            MessageBox.Show("Errors building {0} into {1}","data,txt");
            foreach (CompilerError ce in cr.Errors)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ce.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Source {0} built into {1} successfully.","data.txt");
        }
```

The code in data.txt file has line:

```
Properties.Resources.something
```

Now when I compile code dynamically it shows error:

> Name "Properites" does not exist in current context.

I don't know how to fix it. There is no DLL named **Properties.dll** so I cannot refernce it.
I tried **System.References.dll** but It does not solve the problem.

Edit sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
        public static void Main()
        {
            byte[] resource = Properties.Resources.someresource;

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my search, I find that your source file is wrong. As usual, the source file should end with .cs instead of .txt.

I make a successful code example and you could have a look.

Code:

```
 class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            //  First parameter is the source file name.
            if (File.Exists(args[0]))
            {
                CompileExecutable(args[0]);//  Here args[0] is 'D:\\test.cs'
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input source file not found - {0}",
                    args[0]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input source file not specified on command line!");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("success"); 
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static bool CompileExecutable(String sourceName)
    {
        FileInfo sourceFile = new FileInfo(sourceName);
        CodeDomProvider provider = null;
        bool compileOk = false;

        // Select the code provider based on the input file extension.
        if (sourceFile.Extension.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == ".CS")
        {
            provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
        }
        else if (sourceFile.Extension.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == ".VB")
        {
            provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("VisualBasic");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Source file must have a .cs or .vb extension");
        }

        if (provider != null)
        {

            // Format the executable file name.
            // Build the output assembly path using the current directory
            // and <source>_cs.exe or <source>_vb.exe.

            String exeName = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}.exe",
                System.Environment.CurrentDirectory,
                sourceFile.Name.Replace(".", "_"));

            CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Console.dll");
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll");
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");// I have changed here.
            cp.GenerateExecutable = true;

            // Specify the assembly file name to generate.
            cp.OutputAssembly = exeName;

            // Save the assembly as a physical file.
            cp.GenerateInMemory = false;

            // Set whether to treat all warnings as errors.
            cp.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;

            // Invoke compilation of the source file.
            CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp,
                sourceName);

            if (cr.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                // Display compilation errors.
                Console.WriteLine("Errors building {0} into {1}",
                    sourceName, cr.PathToAssembly);
                foreach (CompilerError ce in cr.Errors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  {0}", ce.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Display a successful compilation message.
                Console.WriteLine("Source {0} built into {1} successfully.",
                    sourceName, cr.PathToAssembly);
            }

            // Return the results of the compilation.
            if (cr.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                compileOk = false;
            }
            else
            {
                compileOk = true;
            }
        }
        return compileOk;
    }
}
```

.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Resources;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
   public  class Student
    {

        public static void Main()
        {
            using (ResXResourceWriter resx = new ResXResourceWriter(@".\CarResources.resx"))
            {
                resx.AddResource("Title", "Classic American Cars");
                resx.AddResource("Name", "test1");
                resx.AddResource("Age", "22");
            }
            Dictionary<string, string> pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            using (ResXResourceReader resxReader = new ResXResourceReader(@".\CarResources.resx"))
            {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resxReader)
                {
                    pairs.Add(entry.Key.ToString(), entry.Value.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(entry.Value);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("success"); 
             Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

When you click the .exe file, you will get the following:
[image]

Comment: I changed it to .cs and it still gives the same error as before.I think it is not important if it is .txt or .cs becouse it just reads code from file. If you want to recreate my error, just add some resource to ConsoleApp1 and try to load it using       `var string = Properties.Resources.resource`

Comment: Can you provide the .cs file?

Comment: I cant add original, but I will edit my post with sample .cs file which throws the same error.

Comment: Based on my research, you need create resource files programmatically. we can't use Properties.Resources.someresource; when we only have a .cs file. I have updated my code, which could create and read resource file.